# Use Python popen to call an image viewer

Tags: python, image-processing

Using a Python script, I want to be able to open an image and close it on Ubuntu.

I'm looking at [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725099/how-can-i-close-an-image-shown-to-the-user-with-the-python-imaging-library), specifically this line:

```
viewer = subprocess.Popen(['some_viewer', infile])
```

What should I put as the `some_viewer`?

Comment: Once you have imagemagick installed you will get a command line option called display along with it.So you can easily use 
`viewer = subprocess.Popen(['display',infile])` .

Comment: Any reason you need a subprocess for this? Look e.g. at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270080/how-to-draw-a-gdkpixbuf-using-gtk3-and-pygobject or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549480/load-and-show-an-image-from-the-web-in-python-with-gtk-3

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gvfs-open` to launch the default application for the filetype.

e.g. `gvfs-open test.png` would open test.png in GPicView on my system, and GIMP on a system where the user has set the default application for opening png files to GIMP.